# Is it possible to set css on appendees in a single statement?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing something like this.

```
$("#accountsTable")
  .append(getHeadersFromJson(json))
  .append(getRowsFromJson(json));
$("#accountsTable")
  .css("border", "3px solid black");
$("#accountsTable th")
  .css("border-bottom", "3px solid black");
$("#accountsTable td")
  .css("border-bottom", "1px solid black");
```

I'd like to set the css's in a single statement. Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: Not on three different elements ?

Comment: i think you can't as selectors are different

Comment: You have 3 different selectors with 3 different CSS styles... There isn't much room for improvement, except that you could possibly move it to CSS instead.

Comment: @adeneo I was curious if it was possible and how it'd look in such a case. Now that I've seen how, I'm certain we agree it's a baaad move to go that way. Please post your comment as a reply so I can accept it.   :)

Comment: @adeneo I got a message that someone complained about me accepting wrong answer or something like that. But when I get to the page, there's nothing new here. Also, the code of yours (if I recall correctly) seems to be gone. Did I do something inappropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to set the same CSS rules for multiple elements, you could do this:

```
$('#accountsTable, #accountsTable th, #accountsTable td')
  .css("border-bottom", "3px solid black");
```

But your rules are all slightly different, so you'd need to target them individually again anyway to achieve what you want. The above line with the two below would do it:

```
$("#accountsTable")
  .css("border", "3px solid black");
$("#accountsTable td")
  .css("border-bottom-width", "1px");
```

But that's no shorter than your original code, and it's a little less clear.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
.css({"border" : "3px solid black", "border-bottom" : "1px solid black"});
```

But, like other comments said, not on different elements. That would set multiple CSS attributes on one element.